# Portable recursive regex substitution within a string to resolve .. in path

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

In Bash, what is the most elegant and portable way to resolve all occurrences of `..` within a string representing a path?

Example: path `/aa/bb/cc/../dd/ee/../../ff/gg/hh/ii/jj/../../../kk` becomes `/aa/bb/ff/gg/kk`

I wrote two functions that mostly accomplish this goal. (It was actually one, and it was longer, but I had a few ideas while writing this question…)

One uses repetition:

```sh
resolve_parents () {
  local previous result=$1
  local re="\/$re|$re\/" re='[^\/]{1,}\/\.\.'
  while [[ $result != $previous ]]; do
    previous=$result
    result=$(echo "$result" | awk '{sub(/\/'$re'/,"")} 1')
  done
  echo "$result"
}

resolve_parents '/aa/bb/cc/../dd/ee/../../ff/gg/hh/ii/jj/../../../kk'
```

And one uses recursion:

```sh
resolve_parents_r () {
  local re="\/$re|$re\/" re='[^\/]{1,}\/\.\.'
  local result=$(echo "$1" | awk '{sub(/\/'$re'/,"")} 1')
  [[ $1 = $result ]] && echo "$1" || resolve_parents_r "$result"
}
```

They do not remove a leading `..`, which would necessitate determining the base directory to get its parent. I am OK with that limitation. Also, it does not fully reduce `aa/..` to an empty string. I suppose I would either need to separately apply a regex at the end without a leading or trailing slash, or add a slash to the string at the start and remove it at the end.

**Background**

I have a function that runs `ln -s "$source" "$target"`. It needs to throw an error if `$source` does not exist. Confirming `$source` exists is straightforward if it is an absolute path, but relative paths must be normalized. I accomplish this by:

```sh
[[ -d $target ]] && target=$target/$(basename "$source")
local abs_source=$source
[[ $source = /* ]] || abs_source=$( cd "$target/../$source" && pwd -P )
```

The first line is necessary to ensure `$target` ends with the target name. Otherwise the `../` would need to be omitted if `$target` is a directory, but would be required if `$target` already ends with intended link name. `cd` works fine for resolving paths containing double dot parent references only if the directory exists. Since the test occurs before the link is created, `$target` unfortunately but necessarily does not exist.

Thus, I am left to determine whether `$source` exists by deleting matches of the regular expression `[^/]+/\.\.` either preceded or followed by a slash, but not both. (I considered deleting the matches and then deleting sequences of `//`, but that can result in a path that was relative becoming absolute or a path that ended in a target name becoming a directory, which would get another target name appended. Yikes!) I cannot use a global regex replace with that pattern, as that could delete sequences like `../..`. I am not aware of a command that does global replace by resetting the search cursor to the beginning of the string upon each match, so I wrote this into a `while` loop.

I hoped to use a pattern stored in `$re` for the sake of simplicity, but that soon became rather complicated when I tried to do the replace with `sed` and found the `+` requires extended regular expressions are sometimes turned on with `sed -E` (on OSX) and sometimes with `sed -r`. Upon replacing `+` with `{1,}`, I found the braces needed escaping for `sed`, but escaping them caused the Bash regex match to fail. I migrated to using `awk` and its `sub` command, which apparently requires the delimiter to be `/`, so I needed to escape those in my pattern as well.

To prevent infinite loops due to an interpretation mismatch between the regex in Bash and `awk`, I first added a counter variable with an arbitrary limit. I improved that to a difference test, so `while [[ $result =~ $re ]] && (( count < 1000 ))` became `while [[ $result =~ $re && $result != $previous ]]`. Then after experimenting with making an actually recursive function, I realized the `$result =~ $re &&` was not necessary.

At this point I start to wonder whether I really care if my `$source`s are nonexistent!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can just use `readlink -m` here:

```
p='/aa/bb/cc/../dd/ee/../../ff/gg/hh/ii/jj/../../../kk'

readlink -m "$p"
/aa/bb/ff/gg/kk
```

As per `readlink --help`:

> `-m, --canonicalize-missing` canonicalize by following every symlink in
>                                   every component of the given name recursively,
>                                   without requirements on components existence

---

**Update:** Here is a standard stack approach to resolve this using `awk`. Consider this awk script:

```
BEGIN {
   FS = OFS = "/"
}
/^\.\.\// {
   $0 = pwd OFS $0  # prefix with pwd if stats with ../
}
{
   for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
      if ($i == "..")
         delete p[k--]  # pop an element from stack
      else
         p[++k] = $i    # push an element into stack
   }
   # print final stack content
   for (i=1; i <= k; i++)
      printf "%s%s", (i>1 ? OFS : ""), p[i]
   print ""
}
```

Save it as `realpath.awk`, then test it as:

```
p='/aa/bb/cc/../dd/ee/../../ff/gg/hh/ii/jj/../../../kk'
awk -v pwd="$PWD" -f realpath.awk <<< "$p"

/aa/bb/ff/gg/kk
```

Comment: I was dumbfounded at how simple that was, but sadly `readlink` on macOS has no such option, and this is for a Mac/Linux setup program.

Comment: I was trying not to have required packages since this script would be responsible for installing Homebrew itself... but perhaps that is the best way.

Answer (score 0):

In 'configure' files which generated by 'autotools' used pretty simple, and looks like very portable approach :)

```
# expand $ac_aux_dir to an absolute path
am_aux_dir=`cd $ac_aux_dir && pwd`
```

Comment: Also I was trying solve this with sed:

    `sed ':z;s,[^/.]*/\.\./*,,;tz'`

1. `:z` is label with custom name z. Beginning of our loop.
2. `s,[^/.]*/\.\./*,,` trying remove first appearance of `something/..` with optional '/' in the end
3. `tz` is "if prevision substitute command replace something, jump to label `z`"